# What parts of a Django project should I not include in Git?

Tags: django, git, svn

I'm not a programmer, and I'm currently in a situation where I'm switching programmers I work with from A to B.

A used SVN for versioning for the project, but B prefers Git.

I currently have a tarball of the entire project site, presumably including a lot of SVN stuff. I'd like to set up a nice, clean Git repository for Programmer B.

What should I exclude from the initial repository?

I'm asking from the basis of a non-programmer with only some familiarity with Django (I'm halfway through the tutorial) and limited Git exposure (I can set up a simple GitHub project, but I'm by no means a whiz) trying to minimize the weight of this new repository.

- Are there folders standard to every Django project that it would be pointless to include?
- Are there folders created by SVN that contain redundant or old versions that I can remove?
- Are there other files or folders that just add weight to a repository and should be trimmed?

Comment: The same as excluded from the SVN one I presume. Also, did you consider converting the repo with `git-svn`?

Comment: I'll look into git-svn. This may be a situation where I don't know what I don't know, if you know what I mean -- I was wondering if there were specific folders in Django that were standard and shared, for instance, so that including them in the repository would be pointless. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/) repo in github for finding common files to ignore in different projects.  For Django it lists:

```
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
local_settings.py
```

local_settings.py would be a local settings file that overrides different production values  stored in your normal settings.py.  In addition to these, I also include *.bak in my .gitignore.

Comment: *.class
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.box  if using vagrant
.project if using eclipse
.pydevproject if using pydev
.sass-cache/ if using sass
.idea/
.settings/
.DS_Store
.vagrant
venv if using virtualenv which you should
.pydevproject